# If it possible connect Loadbalancers DNSname to Route53 using AWS Cloudformation template?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What I trying to connect is Loadbalancer DNS name to to Route53.
Lets look on example.
Here is Loadbabancer from template in Resource:

```
"RestELB" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
        "DependsOn": "AttachGateway",
        "Properties": {
            "LoadBalancerName": {"Fn::Join": ["",["Rest-ELB-", {"Ref": "VPC"}]]},
            "CrossZone" : "true",
            "Subnets": [{ "Ref": "PublicSubnet1" },{ "Ref": "PublicSubnet2" }],
            "Listeners" : [
                {"LoadBalancerPort" : "80", "InstancePort" : "80","Protocol" : "HTTP"},
                {"LoadBalancerPort" : "6060", "InstancePort" : "6060","Protocol" : "HTTP"}
            ],
        }
    },
```

And Here is Route53:

```
"ApiRecordSet" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
      "Properties" : {
        "AliasTarget" :{
          "DNSName" : [
            {"Fn::Join": ["", [{"ElasticLoadBalancer": "DNSName"},"."]]}
          ],
          "EvaluateTargetHealth" : "Boolean",
          "HostedZoneId" : "String"
        },
        "HostedZoneName" : "example.net.",
        "Comment" : "A records for my frontends.",
        "Name" : "api.example.net.",
        "Type" : "A",
        "TTL" : "900",
      }
    }
```

Just to put {"ElasticLoadBalancer": "DNSName"} didn't work. Can someone to suggest or give me correct way to add this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you want to get the attribute `DNSName` for the LoadBalancer whose reference is `RestELB`. So you will need something with `Fn::GetAtt` like (untested)

```
   "ApiRecordSet" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
      "Properties" : {
        "AliasTarget" :{
          "DNSName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "RestELB", "DNSName" ]},
          "EvaluateTargetHealth" : "Boolean",
          "HostedZoneId" : "String"
        },
        "HostedZoneName" : "example.net.",
        "Comment" : "A records for my frontends.",
        "Name" : "api.example.net.",
        "Type" : "A"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me.
I get error in creating stack: "CREATE_FAILED AWS::Route53::RecordSet ApiRecordSet Value of property DNSName must be of type String. "

Comment: I see. Could you test a string instead of an array? Something like ... ` "DNSName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "RestELB", "DNSName" ]}, ` (no square brackets outside the fn:GetAtt )

Answer (score 6):

For anyone reading this answer in 2018, I got mine working using `CanonicalHostedZoneNameID` and not `CanonicalHostedZoneID`

```
"MyRecordSet": {
      "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
      "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneName" : "example.com.",
        "Name": "abc.example.com.",
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
            "HostedZoneId" : {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MyELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"]},
            "DNSName": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MyELB", "DNSName"]},
            "EvaluateTargetHealth": "false"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: That is only if it's a Classic Load Balancer

Comment: For `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer` it's still `CanonicalHostedZoneID`

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to read the CloudFormation documentation on the AWS::Route53::Recordset AliasTarget type:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget.html

This is how it looks in my CloudFormation when creating an alias target for an ELB:

```
"Route53LoadBalancerAlias" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
      "Properties" : {
          "AliasTarget" : {
          "DNSName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ELB", "DNSName" ]},
          "EvaluateTargetHealth" : False,
          "HostedZoneId" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneID" ]}
        },
```

For load balancers, use the canonical hosted zone ID of the load balancer. For Amazon S3, use the hosted zone ID for your bucket's website endpoint. For CloudFront, use Z2FDTNDATAQYW2. For a list of hosted zone IDs of other services, see the relevant service in the AWS Regions and Endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

YAML for deploying a RecordSet referencing an ELB deployed in the same template.

```
  Route53RecordSet:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties: 
      Name: !Ref HostName
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId
      Type: A
      AliasTarget: 
        DNSName: !GetAtt ElasticLoadBalancer.DNSName
        HostedZoneId: !GetAtt ElasticLoadBalancer.CanonicalHostedZoneIDe
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast Forward to 2023
Assuming you are using v2 Load Balancer.

```yaml
  R53Records:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: a.b.c.d.
      Comment: dummy record
      RecordSets:
        - Name: test.a.b.c.d.
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId:  !GetAtt  myLb.CanonicalHostedZoneID
            DNSName: !GetAtt "myLb.DNSName"
```

To keeep in mind
the correct spelling with correct character is `CanonicalHostedZoneID` for a v2 LB and not CanonicalHostedZoneId/CanonicalHostedZoneIDe/CanonicalHostedZoneNameID